# Free Alternative to SoftXPand Duo or smillar software at cheaper price?

Tags: windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors

I was looking for software which would allow me to play 2 games with 2 mice, 2 keyboard, 2 screens on 1 computer, and I found it here: [click](http://www.miniframe.com/products/softxpand-2011-duo.html) [warning: youtube video plays automaticly, here is an [quick install guide](http://www.miniframe.com/knowledge-base.html?catid=2&kbartid=9)]

Is there any free alternative or something smillar at a cheaper price?

Comment: the one who downvoted this, at least say why.

Comment: Not me, but this is violently off-topic. Yes, I flagged it as such.